# How to run (or build then run?) this Mozilla Rhino Debugger?

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

Would like to try [this Rhino Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Debugger) however having problems

I downloaded latest from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino) according to doc it says just simply run:

```
java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.Main [options] [filename.js] [script-arguments]
```

however..it's source code, so I probably need to build it first...(unless there are precompiled download out there?). Assuming I need to build it to get the jar file for debugger, I assume just build the build.gradle file at the root dir. Or run `gradle tasks build` ? When I do that I get error:

> Execution failed for task ':checkstyleMain'.Unable to create a Checker: configLocation {C:\rhino\rhino-1.7.8\checkstyle.xml}, classpath {C:\rhino\rhino-1.7.8\buil
>   dGradle\classes\java\main;C:\rhino\rhino-1.7.8\buildGradle\resources\main}.

So..I'm a bit lost. Been ten years since I've worked with Java, but hopefully I'm missing something simple.

Any experienced Rhino JavaScript devs out there that can point me in the right direction? Should I just stick with using Eclipse? (Had that working, but I'm still curious about this debugger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest rhino from the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino) you provided, at this time it is "rhino-1.7.8.zip". Unzip that and change directory to "rhino1.7.8/lib"; you need the "rhino-1.7.8.jar" in your `CLASSPATH`. Assuming you are in "rhino1.7.8/lib" that should be in your current folder, and you can then do

```
java -cp rhino-1.7.8.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.Main
```

Which should render like

[image: Rhino Debugger]

Comment: And just like that. Kudos sir. Dunno where I missed that in the docs. But I guess that's why StackOverflow is arguably one of the best bits of "documentation" out there :)